# What is the output of this QR reader function?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, camera

I'm currently trying to create a QR Code reader for my Web App and I'm stuck as I am unable to determine the location of the output for the function I've adopted.

I'm using the QR Reader from this tutorial here:

https://www.sitepoint.com/create-qr-code-reader-mobile-website/

So far, I am able to open my phone's camera and take a photo of a QR Code. The function will then process the image and, if it is a valid QR Code, displays the encrypted string/link to me in a text box.

Here's the code that I'm using on HTML:

```html
<main class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <input type=text class=qrcode-text>
        <label class=qrcode-text-btn>
            <input type=file accept="image/*" 
                             capture=environment 
                             onchange="openQRCamera(this); read();"
                             tabindex=-1>
                         </label>

<script>function openQRCamera(node) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        node.value = "";
        qrcode.callback = function (res) {
            if (res instanceof Error) {
                alert("No QR code found. Please make sure the QR code is within the 
camera's frame and try again.");
            } else {
                node.parentNode.previousElementSibling.value = res;
            }
        };
        qrcode.decode(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(node.files[0]);
}
</script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/sitepoint-editors/jsqrcode/master/src/qr_packed.js">
</script>
```

So everything here is working as intended. But moving forward, I want to be to have my QR Codes perform certain actions based on what string the QR reader produces.

For example, if the QR Code captures reads "winner", I would like an alert to pop-up, congratulating the user.

However, I was unsuccessful in locating the output.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the output value of the QR code is produced in the callback function of the qrcode, and passed as the `res` parameter as seen here:

`qrcode.callback = function (res) {`

Also, from the website that you have given, it states that when the reading of the QR code is done, it will run the callback function:

> Once the FileReader has finished reading the file, we assign a callback to the QR library and send the file contents to the decode function of the library. The library will call our callback and either return an Error object or return the value of the QR code as a string.

The output then will be the `res` parameter when there is no error. I have modified your code to popup the value if reading is successful by simply adding `alert(res)` before changing the text value:

```js
<main class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <input type=text class=qrcode-text>
        <label class=qrcode-text-btn>
            <input type=file accept="image/*" 
                             capture=environment 
                             onchange="openQRCamera(this); read();"
                             tabindex=-1>
                         </label>

<script>function openQRCamera(node) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function () {
        node.value = "";
        qrcode.callback = function (res) {
            if (res instanceof Error) {
                alert("No QR code found. Please make sure the QR code is within the 
camera's frame and try again.");
            } else {
                alert(res);
                node.parentNode.previousElementSibling.value = res;
            }
        };
        qrcode.decode(reader.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(node.files[0]);
}
</script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/sitepoint-editors/jsqrcode/master/src/qr_packed.js">
</script>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I'm new to this and I have yet to understand most of the terms used. Thanks again!